How to identify spots in a noisy mono color image using OpenCV and C++?
I have a noisy image with several bright spots that I need to identify and analyze. I've tried using simple thresholding techniques, but the noise level is too high, and it's difficult to isolate the spots accurately.
Here is an example of my image with the spots I want to identify:

I am using OpenCV with C++ and would appreciate guidance on the best approach to identify these spots. Specifically, I need help with:

Preprocessing the image to reduce noise and increase the visibility of the spots.
Identifying and isolating the bright spots.
Outline the identified spots.

This is what I have tried so far:
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

int main() {
    cv::Mat image = cv::imread("image.png", cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
    if (image.empty()) {
        return -1;
    }

    // Thresholding to create a binary image
    cv::Mat binaryImage;
    cv::threshold(image, binaryImage, 200, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY);

    // Finding contours
    std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point>> contours;
    cv::findContours(binaryImage, contours, cv::RETR_EXTERNAL, cv::CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

    // Drawing contours
    cv::Mat outputImage = cv::Mat::zeros(image.size(), CV_8UC3);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++) {
        cv::drawContours(outputImage, contours, (int)i, cv::Scalar(0, 0, 255), 2);
    }

    cv::imwrite("output.png", outputImage);
    return 0;
}


I published a good dot detector in this patent.
The patent is explicitly limited to applications to stained tissue sections, so the method is freely useable for a lot of people.
Here is Python code using DIPlib that implements this dot detector. It should be fairly straightforward to translate this to C++ using DIPlib, and it should be feasible to implement this using a different library, none of the filters used are uncommon. [Disclaimer: I'm an author of DIPlib.]
import diplib as dip
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = dip.ImageRead('/Users/cris/Downloads/3Kw9Q1sl.jpg')
img = dip.MeanTensorElement(img)  # the image posted here is RGB, this turns it into a grayscale image
dot_size = 5  # approximate size of Gaussian that matches the size of dots to detect
smoothing_sigma = 5  # lots of noise here, we need a large sigma

### DOTNESS MEASURE -- https://patents.google.com/patent/US10839512B2/en
shift_distance = int(round((sigma**2 + smoothing_sigma**2)**0.5))
# First for x axis
dxx = dip.ClipLow(-dip.Dxx(img, smoothing_sigma))
dx = dip.Dx(img, smoothing_sigma)
dx_left = dip.ClipLow(dip.Wrap(dx, [shift_distance, 0]))
dx_right = dip.ClipLow(-dip.Wrap(dx, [-shift_distance, 0]))
# Now for y axis
dyy = dip.ClipLow(-dip.Dyy(img, smoothing_sigma))
dy = dip.Dy(img, smoothing_sigma)
dy_left = dip.ClipLow(dip.Wrap(dy, [0, shift_distance]))
dy_right = dip.ClipLow(-dip.Wrap(dy, [0, -shift_distance]))
# Combine
dotness = dip.Power(dxx * dyy * dx_right * dx_left * dy_left * dy_right, 1/6)

### Detect
# Ignore 30 pixels at top and bottom
dotness[:, 0:29] = 0
dotness[:, -30:-1] = 0
# Ignore all local maxima that are not significant enough
mask = dotness > 0.8  # This is the threshold, pick the value you like best!
# Get local maxima
maxima = dip.SubpixelMaxima(dotness, mask)
maxima = np.array([m.coordinates for m in maxima])
# Plot
plt.imshow(img)
plt.scatter(maxima[:, 0], maxima[:, 1], marker='o', s=50, c='none', edgecolors='red')
plt.show()



Looks amazing. I'll try to run it in mine machine and come back with feedback!

It works great for my usecase. I need to research a little bit what the lib is doing, but the overall result looks promising. Thanks a lot!

@gear you can search for functions here: https://diplib.org/diplib-docs/#search — Dx is the first derivative along x, smoothed by a Gaussian. Dxx is the 2nd derivative. ClipLow sets negative values to 0. Power is just an pixel-wise power. Wrap is an integer shift (it wraps when shifting, but this is not really relevant here).

Just a quick idea if you don't have time/resources to pursue Cris's proper, rigorous and scientific approach.
You can get a fairly decent starting point by thresholding at 20% and running a 15x15 median filter over the result. I did it with ImageMagick but you can do it just the same with OpenCV:
magick input.jpg -colorspace gray -threshold 20% -median 15x15 result.png



Thanks! This is actually also one of my recent approches. But as you can see, you get the white corners and still noise which is hard to get rid of. But nevertheless something I'll keep on trying

Try erosion and dilation, two image processing functions available in OpenCV. Erosion erases small white speckles and should be able to erase the noise in your image much better than thresholding. You should be left with a few white pixels where the bright spots are in the image. Then, dilation will enlarge the spots back to about their original size.

Thanks for the keywords! I'll take a look onto it!
